# Formatting Data in excel sheet with blue prism

Tags: vba, excel, blueprism

I'm trying to run a duplicate check In which varying data is pulled from a website and compared to a master list, the master list being stored in Excel. The information from the website is read from a table in which has line breaks. These  breaks are translated over to the data collection they are initially stored in. Some of the data from the website us eventually written to the master list in Excel. So when I read the master list back into Blue Prism to run a duplicate check, the rows that have line breaks are written into a collection as multiple rows (ex. I should have on 7 rows in my collections but am getting 42). Since the rows are not EXACTLY the same between the 2 collections, when it runs the automation does not recognize the duplicates.

The easiest way to solve this would be if I could make the collection rows have no line breaks as soon as the data is read. I've attempted to use the calculation stage to do so with no luck. I'm not sure if it is actually possible to do this, but would appreciate any direction.

Comment: This is a valid problem and there are many possible solutions, but I think for clarity's sake you might want to restate the question in different terms. This would help prevent others from making incorrect assumptions in their answers. For instance: Is Blue Prism getting the data from the website and then storing it in Excel? Or is it simply pulling data from a provided Excel Worksheet in a collection? When you say "multi lined" do you mean that the cell is wrapping the text value to fit the cell bounds? Or are there actual line breaks? I think you're using "cells" for things that might not be

Comment: Alex, thanks so much for the suggestion. I've edited my question hopefully in a way that makes more sense.

Comment: I think you are right to try and strip out all linefeeds when reading - before you enter the data into a BP Collection. Make a code stage or look in the Utility - Strings VBO at composite actions might do this. You just need to remove VbCrLf, or else split by VbCrLf and re-join...

Answer (score 0):

Record an Excel macro to do the data sorting/cleaning in Excel (possibly Text To Columns, etc..) and then include the running of the macro as part of your Blue Prism process by using an action stage and the MS Excel VBO - Run Macro.  Get the process to create an Excel instance (and create a handle data item from that stage), then use Open Workbook (whatever workbook you store your Macro in) and then use the MS Excel VBO - Run Macro (use the same handle created earlier and type in the name of the "macro").

Comment: Is Run Macro a pre-built stage that comes in the MS Excel VBO? Or is it something I need to create myself? My first solution was to create a macro, but could not figure out how to get BP to run the macro.

Comment: Yes, it is under the MS Excel VBO object, just look down the list in the r's. Get the process to create an Excel instance (and create a handle data item from that stage), then use Open Workbook (where you store your Macro) and then use the MS Excel VBO - Run Macro (type in the name of the macro"") Updated answer.

Comment: While this would work, I'm not sure building an external Excel Macro to incorporate into a process is the best avenue. Especially when you can do cell value checks and manipulations with the provided MS Excel VBO and other utilities.

Comment: Excel macros are much faster, stable and precise than BP VBOs for many of the data-manipulation tasks. I've automated quite a few large Excel reports, and manipulating data in Excel trying to exclusively use BP is like using a push-bike and leaving the Harley in the garage to get there faster. Obviously, not everyone is comfortable with macros, but there is no competition. BP can handle many things, but the purpose of RPA is to automate "the task" and interact with "whatever" to achive it, not to be an ultimate solution in and of itself for every step involved.Hence the RunMacro VBO.

Comment: @Badda_Bing I absolutely agree. I've  actually gone in and enhanced/added to the provided MS Excel VBO by adding custom Macros, as well thrown in more action functionality that is built into the MSO VBA library the object is already referencing. That being said I thought it best to provide solutions using the tools we know exist for the person already, even if they are less robust.

Comment: @Alex P Thank you Alex, I understand and you are right there. I've read your solutions below and like them all for testing..(I'd probably go for number 3)... but (without knowing the size of the data-set) if I had to sit for another eternity and wait for BP to dump data from a collection into Excel, I'd probably go and buy myself a toy robot and place it on top of my monitor while a write a VBA macro... :-)

Comment: @Badda_Bing yup, you scoped the weakness of my answer perfectly: this method is NOT process agnostic. You definitely do not want to do #3 if you don't know the size or structure of the data you're going to be looping over. Personally I'd use OLEDB to connect to the Worksheet and then...delete everything and have my bot move on with its life ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what is happening is that the MS Excel VBO is grabbing the data from the Excel Worksheet wholesale. 

This is to say that it's accessing your Worksheet table, copying the cell values BUT not the cell formatting data, and then dumping the values into a BP collection. 
Since it did not bring along any of the original cell formatting data to reference when it went to populate the collection it's just breaking up the values based on crturn/line breaks. Thus, your collection is organized based on that, and not on the original Worksheet cell.
So, with that said, on to a solution!

---

**Solution 1**
Brute force the organization of the incoming Excel cell data to the collection by looping over the Excel Worksheet cell-by-cell.
Run a loop, and in that loop have BP go into the Excel Worksheet and grab the first populated cell it comes across. Run a formatting/cleanup *Calculation* stage over the data. Dump the cell value into a single collection field.
Repeat.


This is...inelegant, expensive at best, and not at all recommended for any medium to large dataset. But it's definitely the best way to do string manipulation and value comparisons before it hits your collection. Since it sounds like your using a Master template then you as-well know what the expected format of your data should be.
This method will enable you implement `Trim()`, `Concat()`, or `Split()` in a *Calculation* stage to better organize your incoming data before you dump it into a collection.


This is also basically what I think you're already trying to do, but cell-by-cell instead of Worksheet row-by-row or table-by-table.

---

**Solution 2**
Clean up the table data you grab from the website before you dump it into the Excel Worksheet.
This is basically **Solution 1**, but in reverse. Simply format/cleanup your data before it hits you Excel Worksheet.
I'm not sure this is any better than **Solution 1**, but, you know, it's something...

---

**Solution 3**
Format the cell data IN the MS Excel Worksheet itself.
Basically rearrange the cells and cell data in the Excel Worksheet into a more predictable format by using the Split, Trim, Merge, or other actions included in the MS Excel VBO. You can also do this using the Data - OLEDB utility object, but that requires some pretty solid understanding of SQL syntax.
This would look like this using the MS Excel VBO:

- Grab the Excel Worksheet data wholesale and dump into a collection
- Count the rows/fields of the collection
- Is that number consistent with the desired/expected format of your data?
- If not, have the bot go back into the Excel Worksheet and reformat the cells by removing any carriage returns/line breaks/whatever else
- Repeat.

However, I'm always reluctant to reformat any original source, as it's then hard to figure out what wrong and where it went wrong when you've changed the original structure of your data. So it's best to always make a copy of the Worksheet before you make any manipulation.

---

Unfortunately I don't have access to my BP environment at the moment or I'd provide you with the act object actions you'd need to do any of this, my bad. Once I do I'll update this answer.